# Different Number of Spaces Depending on the Variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, space

I am trying to create a sort of list that looks something like this:

```
echo thing1          thing2
echo.
```

Then a **for** loop to list text files in a directory and a bit of information like this:

```
echo %var%           %var1%
echo %var%           %var1%
rem and so on
```

But no matter what length the variable is, there will always be 11 spaces which puts it off a bit with the header.

I know I could make some code to detect the length and save a number of spaces in a variable and then add it on.

But I was just wondering if there is another more simple way.

Comment: Well, it depends on which list file to create: a text file (\*.txt) with fixed columns opened later in a text editor or a [comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file (\*.csv) opened later in a spreadsheet application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no mention how exactly the strings are taken so I'll leave this to you.
Here's how you can set spaces between two variables and the result will have fixed length.

```
@echo off
rem http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=424

set max_len=25


set "var11=thing1"
set "var12=thing2"

set "var21=thing1xxxxxx"
set "var22=thing2"

set "var31=thing1xxxxxx"
set "var32=thing2"

call :setSpaces var11 var12
call :setSpaces var21 var22
call :setSpaces var31 var32



goto :eof

:setSpaces var1 var2 [RtnVar]
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var1=!%~1!"
set "var2=!%~2!"

call :strlen0 var1 len1
call :strlen0 var2 len2



set /a needed_spaces=%max_len%-%len1%-%len2%
rem echo %needed_spaces%
set "spaces="
for /l %%a in (1;1;%needed_spaces%) do (
    set "spaces=!spaces! "
)
set line=%var1%%spaces%%var2%


endlocal&if "%~3" neq "" (set %~3=%line%) else echo %line%



exit /b 0
:strlen0  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b
```